# alphabetical instead of UTF orderby in couchbase

Tags: odata, couchbase

I'm using the order by clause sent in oData format to my Couchbase but unfortunately is retrieving in ASCII or UTF order; is there any posibility that it returns in alphabetical order?

Comment: You need to pick a culture/locale/collation and, if the corresponding writing system has both majuscule and minuscule letter forms, pick a case-sensitivity. [Sorry, I don't know the answer but it would need to address such a requirement from you. Perhaps it needs to be done in client-side code.] If you are presenting ordered data to a user, you might want to base the requirement on their expectation, or system or browser configuration, or location.

Comment: Well thnks any ways for the try, in fact one approach that I was using is ordering the data after retreive it, but I think its not right... Anyways what I´m doing instead is to change to lowercase all the files when saving for now...

But image that the data is already there and change the fileNames to lower case is forbidden or impossible due some expected behaviors, maybe adding other field could be other approach...